# DNS, IP and PORT confusing behaviour

Tags: port, host

I have LINUX web server on local network on IP `192.168.1.200` (this is Xtreamer nas server) and I want to access it through win notebook from local wifi.

I have HOST file record `192.168.1.200 server.com`

Note that `ping server.com` returns `192.168.1.200` as expected

Could anybody explain why

`192.168.1.200:8080` returns xtreamer configuration page as expected

BUT

`server.com:8080` returns

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Microsoft-IIS/5.0 Server at server.com Port 8080`

I thought that it should returns same pages. What I dont understand is Microsoft-IIS in result when xtreamer has Linux inside.

Answer (score 0):

Either because your browser is using DNS to find the IP address of `server.com` and won't check the hosts file or because the web server is not configured to reply to queries with a Host of `server.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Xtreamer is built on Linux with Apache including `ModSecurity`. ModSecurity also allow to fake server signature eg.

`SecServerSignature "Microsoft-IIS/5.0"`

And this is what Xtreamer do.